# Spark Streaming on real time message files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement in my project to process the message files(.txt) in real time. I used to receive message files from 3rd party in real time to our landing zone and from there we should pick up the files for processing. Below is the data flow proposed.

Source --> Landing Zone --> HDFS --> PySpark --> Parquet/CSV --> Data Store

Whenever i see a new file in landing zone, that should be picked up and moved to HDFS and from then, the downstream process should process it in real time. Can i approach this use case with PySpark streaming? If so, kindly share some details and links if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **Spark Structured Streaming** to process the message files in realtime. Structured Streaming supports various input sources, you can configure to use '**FileSource**' as a datasource.

Filesource reads files written in a directory as a stream of data. Supported file formats are text, csv, json, orc, parquet. Note that the files must be **atomically** placed in the given directory, in your case it will work fine as you are moving the file atomically from Landing Zone to HDFS.

For more details, Refer to: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources
for API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader

Note Structured Streaming supports reading data from nested directories, we can provide globpaths as an input to Filesource path. Refer to: [Spark Structured Streaming - Read file from Nested Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605098/spark-structured-streaming-read-file-from-nested-directories/51695427#51695427)